# When appending a tuple to a list, I can append (a + b + c) or (a, b + c) or (a + b, c) but appending (a, b ,c) causes the program to refuse to run

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, append

Here's the code

```
def check_right_angle(a, b, c):
    if a**2 + b**2 == c**2:
        return True
    return False

def mn_to_abc(m, n):
    return m**2 - n**2, 2 * m * n, m**2 + n**2

list_solutions = []

for i in range(1001): #Getting all primitive triples using Euclid's formula <= 1000
    list_solutions.append([])
    if i == 0:
        continue
    for m in range(1, int(i/2) - 1):
        n = int(i / (2 * m) - m)
        if m > n and n > 0:
            a, b, c = mn_to_abc(m, n)
            if check_right_angle(a, b, c) and a + b + c == i:
                list_solutions[i].append((a, b, c))

for item in list_solutions: #Getting the remaining triples by using the primitive triples
    for abc in item:
        for i in range(1, 85): # 85 since 3x + 4x + 5x = 1000 => x = 83.3333 = 84
            try:
                new_a = abc[0] * i
                new_b = abc[1] * i
                new_c = abc[2] * i
                if new_a + new_b + new_c <= 1000:
                    list_solutions[new_a + new_b + new_c].append((new_a, new_b, new_c))
                else:
                    break
            except:
                continue

print(len(list_solutions[120]))
print(list_solutions[120])
```

The situation is mostly explained in the title but this code refuses to run unless line 30 is replaced with either one of the following lines:

```
                    list_solutions[new_a + new_b + new_c].append((new_a+ new_b, new_c))
                    list_solutions[new_a + new_b + new_c].append((new_a+ new_b+ new_c))
                    list_solutions[new_a + new_b + new_c].append((new_a, new_b+ new_c))
```

I've even tried to append it as a list instead of a tuple but to no avail. Such a weird thing to run into.

Comment: please provide the error with stack

Comment: I don't get an error. The code just kept running indefinitely. Even doing ctrl + c didn't stop it, I had to close down vscode. I've just figured out why it's not working, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Never mind fellas, just had an epiphany. Turns out adding to a list you're iterating is a terrible, terrible idea. Before line 30 I added this code:

```
if not (new_a, new_b, new_c) in list_solutions[new_a + new_b + new_c]:
```

You might have noticed that I'm still adding to that same list I'm iterating through, but for some reason, as long as the items in that list don't repeat themselves, everything is fine.
I would close this question now, but it's telling me I can only accept my own answer in 2 days.